# How can i create a framed image and adjust caption-frame spacing without using tikz package?

Tags: spacing, floats, captions

I need to add frames to all my images in my file. Captions must stay outside - below the frames - and the frame-caption spacing should be adjusted to a definite value.

I used `\floatstyle{boxed}` and `\restylefloat{figure}` commands with `float` and `floatrow` packages. These solved my framing problem, but I could not adjust the frame-caption spacing.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}  
\usepackage[turkish]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}   
\begin{document}  
\begin{figure}[h!] 
\centering  
\scalebox{0.6}{\includegraphics{bandstr}}  
\caption{Band structure of a crystal}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This code creates a framed image with the caption just under the border, without any spacing:
[image]
How can I adjust the spacing between the caption and the frame border?

Comment: Welcome! Without an MWE it is highly unlikely that any work people put into helping you will be useful to you. So if you really can't create an MWE, then you are probably going to have to solve this on your own. People might make some guesses as answers, if they are looking for something to do. But the chances of those answers working in your `very complicated` document are really quite low. Also, I have no idea what `adjusting frame-caption spacing lacked` means, even with the addition of an exclamation mark.

Comment: `14pt` is not a valid option. Using `h` as the sole specifier for a float is a Seriously Bad Idea.

Comment: @cfr I edited my question, and deleted my first comment.

Comment: Thanks. I tidied up your question a little. Please roll-back if you think I misunderstood your meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The **caption** package provides extensive options for caption customisation.

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

It can be used to adjust the `boxed` float style, including the skip between the box and the caption.

```
\captionsetup[boxed]{skip=20pt}
```

Note that `20pt` is clearly too large. It is used here just to illustrate the effect.

I didn't have a picture of the structure of crystals, so I substituted a couple of cats instead. I hope you'll agree that this is a great improvement.

[The relevant cat codes are available in other answers or on request. However, I must admit that the feline elements of this solution *do* require Ti*k*Z.]

[image: feline partners]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float,caption}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}
\captionsetup[boxed]{skip=20pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}% don't use the h specifier on its own!
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{cathod}
  \caption{Striped structure of feline partners}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @crf for your clear and immediate answer. It works well. `15pt` is a better choise for my work. 
Under similar problems there are billions of answers but they are not economic and untidy, at least for me.

Comment: Is it possible to adjust frame width with only small changes, since it comes me that frame wells over the text width. This is, unfortunately, an unacceptable situation for our university.

Comment: @YasinŞale This is an aspect of the style you've chosen from the `float` package. From page 11 of the manual `The boxed float style puts the float into a box (which is slightly larger than the
usual \textwidth). `.

Comment: You're right, i've read that part of manual, but again had a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use the `float` package if I could help it. I'd stick to a more flexible approach and add the frames within the floating environment, when needed. Or define a custom command. Or follow the package suggestions from the `caption` manual's discussion of `float`. You could, obviously, redefine the `boxed` style, but I don't see what would be gained by that. If you don't really want this style, easier not to use it.